# How many requests can PHP handle per second?

Tags: php

Inorder to create a SaaS application..

- How many requests PHP can handle per second ?
- How to handle millions of requests per second?
- What is the best database technology to handle millions of requests?

Comment: Server with better hardware specification can handle more requests. Not related to PHP.

Comment: `How many requests PHP can handle per second ?` - As many as the webserver you're using can

Comment: "Not related to PHP" That is the thing i want to know. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP. This is a server-related issue. PHP does not interpret the requests , It's the webserver which does it.

Get a high-precision server that can balance loads of requests. You can also avail for *pay-as-you-use* services from different webhosting providers.

It's *awkward* to provide you links for such webhosting services since you can easily google it up and find some of  them out. However, r---space and med----mple offers great services (***names masked to avoid advertizing***)

Answer (score 8):

This is totally hardware dependent. With infinite resources and perfect load balancing PHP can handle all requests that could ever originate in the universe.